# WatchKit see if crown is pressed or screen flipped/tilted

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

I have made an app that uses the AppleWatch.

I want to call `NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget` when the user goes to the home screen, but continue if they put down their wrist

Is there any way I can see the difference in `-(void)didDeactivate`?

Kim

Comment: - You can't detect when the crown is pressed in, only when it is rotated.  Source: Apple Docs (https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller).


- Look at the methods for `WKInterfaceController`: https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller


- `willDisappear()` might suit your needs but there is not enough information in your question for why you need this.

Comment: The same methods will be called whether or not the screen goes to sleep or they leave the app.  There might be some help found in using `NSNotification`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29635072/exit-from-a-watchkit-app-is-handled-by-the-watchkit-os-itself-i-dont-need-to-c